# Add title attribute to oEmbed iframe for accessibility

Tags: oembed

On page https://dekamarkt.meoconcept.nl/video/ there is a video in an iframe element. This iframe element has been given a title attribute with a description, this is well taken into account. However, it should also be made clear what kind of content this iframe contains. This can be done by adding “Video” to the description in the title attribute. This also applies to the iframe with the video on the page.

In Wordpress “Video” isn’t be added by default, but maybe there is a filter to add this?

Comment: keep in mind the iframe isn't generated by WordPress, it's generated by Youtube and given to WordPress. You could write code to modify what YT provided but it may not be reliable if Google decides to change their markup